# Jquery ползунок мульти

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, какой порекомендуете плагин/решение для реализации ползунка по типу (jquery UI slider). Важно что бы инициализировался 1 раз в 
Решение на jquery UI не подходит потому что каждый раз нужно инициализировать js
Есть ли какое нибудь решение которое будет автоматически задавать, а мне оставалось лишь дублировать html блоки. В идеале если бы вставил вот такой код

```
<div class="slider">
<input value="0">
<input value="100">
</div>
```

а он уже самостоятельно сгенерировал ползунок?

Comment: Не понял, что значит "один раз"? Кто мешает инициализировать jQuery UI один раз? `$( ".slider" ).slider();` - и все слайдеры инициализировались.

Comment: Чем не устраивает нативное решение? http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php